# Remember ssh passphrase until user logs off

Tags: ssh, passphrase

I use a passphrase protected ssh keyfile to connect to a server.
Each time I open a new terminal I have to re-enter the passphrase. Can I make Ubuntu remember the passphrase until I log-off or for an hour or so?

Comment: Just for a better understanding: Can you log in via username and password to your server? I think I can provide you an easy way to do it so but it implies logging in via username/password.

Comment: I can also login via username/pw.

Comment: Ok, with that in mind I have made an answer for you. Give it a try and let us know if this also works for you. Thank you and Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sshpass` in combination with ssh in order to login to a server.

You can install `sshpass` via `sudo apt-get install sshpass` if your haven't already.

The trick is the usage of both sshpass and ssh in a single line like this:

```
sshpass -p "YOURPASSWORD" ssh user@server.com -p 2222
```

But that's something you already knew. And in order to avoid writing your password everytime you wish to log in to your server you can create a custom script which will execute that command for you when you write its name, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p "YOURPASSWORD" ssh user@server.com -p 2222
```

Change the proper data, save the code in a file and name it whatever you wish, easy to remember and easy to type. Please note that I am using `-p 2222` because that's the port number I use instead of `22`, your server may use `a different port number` so check for that information if something seems not to be working as expected.

I am going to name it `ssh1` and give it the proper execution permissions with:

```
sudo chmod +x ssh1
```

Then move the script to your `/usr/bin` folder with `sudo mv ssh1 /usr/bin`, provide your user password and that's it.

After this you can enter any terminal, write your script's name (`ssh1` in this case) and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and the script will do the trick for you.

A screenshot of my custom script in action is here:

[image]

***NOTE: You must manually log in to your ssh server at least once in your life in order to the script be able to automatically do its magic.***

Good luck!